# Loading remote html into div container but preventing it from loading content

Tags: jquery, json

I am looking to load some remote content into a `DIV` via a local script which `GET`s the HTML from a target URL using jQuery.

Once I have the HTML how can I load it into the container and prevent the content from executing external CSS stylesheets and favicons etc.

So I want the HTML available to jQuery to load images for instance but don't want them to display in my webpage.

I believe the way is to load the external content as escapable json is this true? If so how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean U just want to load the remote content but do not display it in your page?
If so ,just add the content to a element out the "body"

e.g.

```
<body>
...
</body>
<remotecontainer>
<!-- load remote images here -->
</remotecontainer>
```

Comment: No, I want to load it into a div but prevent it from running. Not just hide it...

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with this?

You can insert the code inside a  tag to prevent it from loading only showing the code, or you can strip all the img/link tags away from it.

One way would also be to recode the < and > into html codes. (eg < >)

Comment: I want to load remote content and manipulate certain elements using jQuery. E.g. I want to be able to scroll through remote images.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is the [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag, perhaps with the `<code>` tag.

If you use html entities for special characters like `<` and `>` you can display code, like so:

```
&lt;img src="image.png" /&gt;
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QTgrB/) to show how it works.

Another way to display html as text would be to just insert it as a text node, something like:

```
var html = '<script type="text/javascript"></script>';
$('element').text(html);
```